# What are the differences between the divisions: Open, Co-Rec, Greek, Women

Tags: terminology

What do each of these divisions mean: Open, Co-Rec, Greek, Women

Comment: I didn't change it that much, at least in my opinion. I understood where he was getting at. I have a lot of friends that play intramural sports and I had always wondered what the divisions were/meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These divisions usually pop up in college intramural sports. The most common of these sports include: volleyball, kickball, dodgeball, wiffleball, badminton, bowling, ultimate frisbee, Eclipse Ball, and Sports Trivia.

- Co-Rec

  Co-Rec teams are comprised of a specific number of male and female players on the field/court at a time. The ratio of male players to female players on the field at one point in time must always be even. *For example, if your team has 6 players, you must have 3 male and 3 female.* Individuals and teams in this division compete on a recreational basis with the emphasis on having fun and socializing with other students. Skill levels vary from beginner through advanced.
- Open

  Open leagues allow any number or men and/or women to compete in this division. There are no restrictions in this type of league.  Teams can be all men, all women, or any combination of the two. Skill levels also vary from beginner through advanced.
- Women

  This one is pretty self-explanatory. Women leagues can only be comprised of female athletes. No male players can be on the roster or on the field.
- Greek

  This division is limited to only those who belong to a fraternity or sorority in college. Any individuals that are not apart of the [IFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North-American_Interfraternity_Conference), [MGC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Multicultural_Greek_Council), [NALFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Association_of_Latino_Fraternal_Organizations), [NPHC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Pan-Hellenic_Council), or [Panhellenic Council](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panhellenic_Council) cannot join a *Greek* league.